# why the function is returning none for no reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function is returning a None after final print. What could be the cause?(please go easy on me,i am just a beginner.)

```
def prime(n):
    prime = [True for i in range(n+1)] #Boolean array for prime[0,n]
    p=2
    while (p*p<=n):
        if prime[p]==True: #Checking if marked or not
            for i in range(p*p,n+1,p):
                prime[i] = False #Marking multiples of p
    p+=1
    for p in range(2,n): #Getting values for true values
        if prime[p]:
           print(p)
print(prime(30))
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to explain what you are trying to achieve. The function returns  None most likely because you are trying to print the result of a function that returns nothing.

Comment: In your case, you have to call `prime(30)`, without *print* word

Comment: May I introduce you to [rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/), I think this might solve your problem here ;)

Comment: One another issue may be the indentation used ```p+=1```. It should be inside the ```while``` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`None` is the default return value of a function (or the absence of it, because that's what `None` is).